# Ever used a hopback?

Tags: hopback

I'm curious to hear stories about using a hopback.  There are a few incarnations out there and a few reasonable DIY hopbacks.

I'm wondering if it's worth the trouble.  And, if so, does anyone have tips on using one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used a hopback, and I now consider it an indispensable part of my rig.

I use it primarily to filter out any sediment, hop solids, etc before the wort goes through my plate chiller, since it would be very difficult to get particles out of there, if they got in.

I will sometimes use it without any hops in it, or with other ingredients (like fruit) if appropriate for the recipe.

If you are interested, I have described my [hopback setup](http://kaeding.name/articles/2007/02/03/on-hopbacks/) in more detail on my blog.

Comment: That's interesting.  Do you just use gravity feed through the hopback and chiller?

Comment: @Scott Yeah, gravity is all it takes.  I set up the kettle on a table, with the hopback and chiller on a chair, and the fermenter on the floor.